# Javascript console log trims newline into space character

Tags: javascript

In nodeJs,

```
console.log("before ", "\n", "after")
```

I expect the output,

```
before

after
```

But it prints,

```
before
 after
```

Comment: Not in my browser (Firebug's console prints everything on one line). What's your question, by the way?

Comment: `console.log` behavior is not standard. In chrome, multiple arguments are all printed in one line. Some other browsers will treat each argument in a different line.

Comment: @MinusFour Wich browser for example? I tried with Iron (chromium), Firefox, Internet Explorer, Edge and they all print in one line.

Comment: @ShanShan I can't say which ones do that. I guess what I tried to say is that other browsers **can** print each argument in a separate line as there is no standard that they need to adhere to.

Comment: @MinusFour I see. It's not standard but today, I think the behaviour is consistent across the most used javascript engines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get these spaces " " in your Browser,  is that it will add a space-symbol inbetween every argument:

```
console.log("before ", "\n", "after")
```

will be like:

```
"before  \n after"
```

To avoid these spaces do string concatenation by your own:

```
console.log("before " + "\n" + "after")
```

Also if you want a blank line inbetween use two `\n`:

```
console.log("before " + "\n\n" + "after")
```

And remember `Console.log()` is a non-standard  feature, a stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log):

> **Non-standard**
>    This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

`\n` means one line feed. If you want two line feed you should use `\n\n`. Like  this

```
console.log("before ", "\n\n", "after")
```

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is to put the output on different lines, you'll want to use string concatenation. To achieve the output you would like to see, try the following:

```
console.log('before' + '\n\n' + 'after');
```

The result will be:

```
before

after
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want end result

```
before

after
```

Then Try

```
console.log("before\n\nafter");
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is observed in Nodejs command line execution. You just need to change your code-

`console.log("before\nafter");`